# In Android, is there a way to display the bearing/heading indicator on google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location, bearing

Is there a way to to enable this on my map?
[image]

All the posts that I have searched explain only how to calculate the bearing...
Doesn't Google Maps API include that?

thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is a way ! [check this document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#my-location)

Comment: @ Blackkara do you mean this: `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`? It only shows the location, not the bearing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Feb 2019: any updates on this? I don't even know the keywords to look for.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a symbol, for example

`google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW`

Then set its rotation to the heading value.

You may need to provide your own SVG file if you want the fading effect.

API here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols